# Why does string interpolation work in one example, but not the other?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm puzzled by the code bellow:

```cs
CultureInfo provider = new("pt-BR");
DateTime date = new(2023, 1, 1);
var str1 = $"January is the same as {date:MMMM}";
var str2 = String.Create(provider, $"January is different from {date:MMMM}");
Console.WriteLine(str1); // Outputs: January is the same as January
Console.WriteLine(str2); // Outputs: January is different from janeiro
```

How does string interpolation works?

For `str1` it seems straightforward: the compiler can expand the brackets into string concatenations and ToString()'s. Eg: `"January is the same as " + date.ToString("MMMM")`

But `str2` shows that's not the case. The `$""` block seems to be passed unaltered to the `String.Create` method.

Considering this could be an arbitrary method, in what moment does the interpolation happens? How can the `String.Create` method change the interpolation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the original type of interpolated string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38119074/what-is-the-original-type-of-interpolated-string)

Comment: @shingo: If there's an answer to the OP's question there, I don't see it.  It might actually be buried in there somewhere, but I didn't take the time to carefully read the whole thing.

Comment: @Alexandre: You state that 'The $"" block seems to be passed unaltered to the String.Create method,' but you also claim that this code outputs "January is different from janeiro".  Given that your CurrentCulture might be different from the one you're providing to String.Create, why do you think this is wrong?

Comment: The second parameter to `String.Create` is an interpolated string *handler*, not just an interpolated string.

Comment: In order to use a culture with string interpolation, you have to assign the interpolation string to a `FormattableString` and then call `ToString()` on that: `FormattableString str = $"January is the same as {date:MMMM}"; var str1 = str.ToString(provider);`

Comment: Or alternatively `var str1 = ((FormattableString)$"January is the same as {date:MMMM}").ToString(provider);`

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Interpolated string handlers can do this, too.  [See what the compiler generates](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAExAagD4AEBMBGAsAKHQAYACdbAOgHEAbAe2AhqgC8IAXKOmAbgIPQBmMphIBhEgG8CJWWWHoALCQCyACgCUUmXN1iArjXb6ATgFMAkjABmdEgAcTdAG5QEZkyQC8JGGYDuagBE9uwAtABCAEpBGnz4uroAIhxmACpQYGYkCKnevgFqmESYgnAk2OXYcTqJJLWJzhCeAM7sJqI+AMrtsADmFGLmqWqOLm4e5QAkQQBSEDD6zQCeJFAtOVDW1h5mMOwk1k5gUrnsZiAqVyoAvrHxujcEN0A=)

Comment: "An interpolated_string_expression is classified as a value. If it is immediately converted to System.IFormattable or System.FormattableString with an implicit interpolated string conversion (§10.2.5), the interpolated string expression has that type. Otherwise, it has the type string." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions